# Asterisk showing busy

Tags: asterisk

I am trying to pass call via sip phone and I was success when I tried for the first time but after that I can't connect the call showing the message below. Can any one give me a solution why this happening, if the configuration is not ok then how I could successfully call for the 1st time. If so then what is the problem?

My configuration is below

### Sip.conf

Answer (score 2):

You dialed extension 10001, but it is engaged (busy). Hang up that phone and try again.